# Editing data marked as unique

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

So I have my model which briefly looks like this:

```
@Column
@NotNull
@Size(min = 3)
private String firstname;

@Column
@NotNull
private String lastname;

@Column
@UniqueUsername(message = "Such username already exists")
private String username;
```

Then there is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "editUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        return "editUser" ;
    }
    model.addAttribute("roles", roleRepository.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("user", userService.findOne(id));
    userService.editUser(id, user);
    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}
```

this is the view

[image]
I'm using thymeleaf as my template engine.

So I've got the simplest form there is consisting of firstname, lastname, username
and I'd like to be able to edit only lastname but when I send the form it violates the unique constraint on my username field ( which is kinda obvious ).
The goal is to be able to edit one of the user's attributes but preserving the others. How do I do it?

Comment: Comment `@UniqueUsername(message = "Such username already exists")`

Comment: yeah but this will allow the same usernames in my database which I don't want to do

Comment: This is exception is because, for edit also it is considering it as save and checking for unique..so for edit you are getting this exception

Comment: Yes I know. I realize that when I put the data in the database it is empty thus no unique constraint is happening. The problem is when I edit the data ( my goal ). How do I go around it? I want to be able to edit a username and at the same time keep it unique

Comment: Comment it here...on saving new one explicitly check for the existence...and edit requires no changes.

Comment: Could you also add to your question, the code inside the method : `userService.editUser(id, user);` ?

Comment: I didnt post it because the controller didn't even reach this method